# Angular 4 selected not working in option with *ngFor

Tags: angular, html-select, ngfor, angular-forms

`<option [selected]="true">` is not working in Angular 4 if it is also present an ngFor.

**Template:**

```
<form [formGroup]='myForm'>

  <div class="col-sm-9 col-md-4">
    Not working selected, with ngFor
    <select formControlName="nationality" class="form-control">
      <option *ngFor="let elem of nationalityList" [ngValue]="elem.code" [selected]="elem.code=='ITA'">{{ elem.description}}</option>
    </select>
  </div>

  <div class="col-sm-9 col-md-4">
    Working selected, without ngFor
    <select formControlName="nationality" class="form-control">
      <option [ngValue]="nationalityList[0].code" [selected]="nationalityList[0].code=='ITA'">{{ nationalityList[0].description}}</option>
      <option [ngValue]="nationalityList[1].code" [selected]="nationalityList[1].code=='ITA'">{{ nationalityList[1].description}}</option>
    </select>
  </div>

</form>
```

**Component:**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormControl } from "@angular/forms";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-prova',
  templateUrl: './prova.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./prova.component.css']
})
export class ProvaComponent implements OnInit {

  myForm:FormGroup = new FormGroup({
    nationality: new FormControl('')
  });

  nationalityList = [
    { description: 'NATIONALITY_ITALIAN', code: 'ITA' },
    { description: 'NATIONALITY_FOREIGN', code: 'EST' }
  ];

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

**Output:**

[image]

So the question is: **why doesn't selected work with ngFor? Is it a bug or am I missing something? How to make it work?** Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not use selected, try this:

```
<form [formGroup]="myForm">
  <select formControlName="nationality" class="form-control">
    <option *ngFor="let elem of nationalityList" [ngValue]="elem.code">
      {{ elem.description}}
    </option>
  </select>
</form>
```

And change your myForm definition to:

```
myForm:FormGroup = new FormGroup({
  nationality: new FormControl('ITA')
});
```

Comment: Yes I think this is the solution... Still remains with no explanation why selected doesn't work with ngFor. If it's a bug maybe it should be poitned out? If you build the form in a different file set the default value in ngOnInit with this.myForm.controls.nationality.setValue(this.nationalityList[0].code);

Comment: I guess because you already had a `formControlName="nationality"`, and it ignored the one in the select without `*ngFor`

Answer (score 1):

if that's helpful i used to declare an NGmodel for that matter and set it's value intially in my ts file according to my needs , just like this :

```
   <select [(ngModel)]="myval" formControlName="nationality" class="form-control"> 
    <option *ngFor="let elem of nationalityList" [ngValue]="elem.code" [selected]="elem.code=='ITA'">{{ elem.description}}</option> 
    </select>
```

in my ts file I used :

```
export class ProvaComponent implements OnInit {
  myval:any; // or your type
  myForm:FormGroup = new FormGroup({
    nationality: new FormControl('')
  });

  nationalityList = [
    { description: 'NATIONALITY_ITALIAN', code: 'ITA' },
    { description: 'NATIONALITY_FOREIGN', code: 'EST' }
  ];

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
   this.myval = this.nationalityList[0]; // for example
  }

}
```

May not always work, but does the job in some cases.

Comment: I used to do this but [(ngModel)] alongside formControlName created problems in production environment, maybe for code minification...